# How can I sum values with multiple conditions including different dates

Tags: arrays, date, multidimensional-array, excel-2010, sumifs

I have some data as follow (column A:D contain data, column E is the sum I created):

```
NO              
SE  

Date        Country ID  Value   Sum
30-01-2014  SE  B-08888 10  10  
05-02-2014  SE  B-08888 23      
06-02-2014  SE  B-08888 20      
13-05-2014  SE  B-08888 17  27  
14-05-2014  SE  B-08888 10      
13-05-2014  NO  A-07777 15  35  
14-05-2014  NO  A-07777 20
```

I would like to sum all values that are having same country and same ID when: 1) the date is greater than 1/5; and 2) when date is less than 1/5.

I am using the `SUMIFS`. But the `SUMIFS` doesn't give correct results when I included the date argument which is less than 1/5.

```
=SUMIFS($D$5:$D$11;$A$5:$A$11;"<="&DATE(2014;5;1);$B$5:$B$11;A2;$C$5:$C$11;C5) ==> gives incorrect result (=10)

=SUMIFS($D$5:$D$11;$A$5:$A$11;">="&DATE(2014;5;1);$B$5:$B$11;A2;$C$5:$C$11;C8) ==> gives correct result (=27)
```

Is there a way I can take into account both date conditions (i.e. date greater than and less than 1/5) and make the formula general so I don't have to go through every cell to change reference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, the second formula returns `27` for me - so I assume the cell references you have not mentioned are as I have guessed. The first formula for me returns `53` - I suspect the result you want, though have not mentioned.

Something is wrong with your data (not the formulae). The most likely cause is that there is a trailing space in C6 and C7 that is not in C5. Copying C5 down to C9 should fix that. There might however be a data issue in other cells in those two rows.

It might make things easier for you if the formulae were in separate columns.